# Erase kiosk session data on restart

Tags: google-chrome-os, kiosk, chromebook

I'm implementing a web app for ChromeOS Kiosk mode, the app needs to download/upload files and downloaded files need to be removed on every kiosk restart, so new kiosk sessions don't have access to files from the previous sessions.

I found `DeviceEphemeralUsersEnabled` policy, but the policy affects all users enrolled in the device.
I need something which will be erasing only kiosk session data.